# "an (among other things) schizophrenic" or "a (among other things) schizophrenic"?

Tags: grammar

I'm lost on whether I should use "a" or "an" in the part of the sentence: "an (among other things) schizophrenic". How does the part in the brackets affect the rest here?

Comment: "(among other things) a schizophrenic"

Answer (score 1):

Back in high school one helpful tip a teacher gave to me was if the following word starts with a vowel use 'an', otherwise use 'a'.

> "He is **a soldier**, while she is **an athlete**."

The parenthesis act like commas, in which a subordinate clause is enclosed between them. You could phrase it that way but most people are used to something like:

> "He is, among other things, a schizophrenic."

Both work similarly, in which if you remove the subordinate clause the sentence still makes sense:

> "He is a schizophrenic."